# My textures on the house is showing in viewport shading mode, however, when I render the house the textures does not show. How can I fix this?

Tags: rendering, texturing

[image]

[image]

[image]

The first photo is of the house with the textures. The second photo is a rendered image where the texture on the house is not showing and also the man is not suppose to be there.

Comment: in the Outliner make sure that the visibility of the man is disabled in render, and also maybe you have duplicated the house and disabled the visibility of the copy in preview as well?

Comment: The problem I had with the man is fixed, thank you. I did check for duplicates on the house and couldn't find any. Is there a different way to go about this?

Comment: maybe share your file, the house only? https://blend-exchange.com/ don't forget to pack the image (File > External Data > Pack Resources)

Comment: I am a bit new to blender. I am not sure how to only share the house.

Comment: save the file uner another name, select the house, press ctrl i to invert the selection, press x to delete, pack the image, save and share   ;)

Comment: The file is to big to upload on blend-exchange.com

Comment: use another platform like workupload.com

Comment: https://workupload.com/file/XMNtVrGFURJ  Will this work?

Comment: it seems to work but anyway you've left a lot of other objects, and for these objects the render option is still activated in the Outliner. Make sure that you've disabled the render option for all the objects that you don't want to see in the final render (camera icon in the Outliner)

Comment: I only want to figure out why the texture is not showing when I start to render. All the activated objects are the objects I want in the final render.

Comment: are you sure there is not an object that is hiding the house, because if I deactivate in render all the hidden objects in preview, it works

Comment: I tried only rendering this part of the house as well. I uploaded the photo of what happened. I am not sure what you mean by "deactivating in render", can you maybe share a screenshot?

Comment: in the Outliner, if I deactivate the camera icon for the objects that have the eye icon deactivated, i get a correct render

Answer (score 0):

Display the *Disable in Renders* option in the *Outliner* (camera icon, it is displayed by default in the latest versions of Blender):

[image]

Then synchronise the option with the *Hide in Viewport* option (eye icon):

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. It is working now. :)